# Find product of numbers different from 0 in

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the product of all elements different than 0 on two-dimensional array. (4.4) In the case. But my output is wrong. Where I am wrong.

```
int count = 0;
int product = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (A[i][j] != 0) {
            ++count;
            product += A[i][j];
        }

    }
}
if (count != 0) {
    product *= product;
    cout << "product of numbers different from 0: \n" << product;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing the square of the sum, not the product?

Comment: `int product = 0;` and `product += A[x][y];`. You are computing the sum, not the product. (And then squaring it).

Comment: You are not summing over all the array you should change `i < 4` by `i <= 4` and use `(i-1)` in place of `i`when accessing the array (due to `++i`). Same applies for j. And here `x` and `y` are not defined...

Comment: @Gahbu: You misunderstand how `for` loops work in C/C++. This code computes the indices correctly. There's no reason to make the changes you suggest. You are, however, right about the `x` and `y` variables.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, yes my bad, I am visibly too tired right now ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factors have to be multiplied not added:

```
int count = 0;
int product = 1;
           // ^ init with 1

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (A[i][j] != 0) {
            ++count;
            product *= A[x][y];
                 // ^ multiply with factor
        }

    }
}
if (count != 0) {
    cout << "product of numbers different from 0: \n" << product;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful to show the specific lines you changed, and explain why you changed them.